# SQL Server stored procedure for getting rows from table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a stored procedure to retrieve rows from my database table... but it looks like I am missing some thing while typing query.

Here is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[p_GetLeaveRecord_LMS]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @LeaveType varchar(50),
    @IdEmployee int,
    @DateFrom date,
    @DateTo date,
    @Reason nvarchar(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SElECT * FROM cor_leave
    (
    id_leave_type,
    id_employee,
    dt_from,
    dt_to,
    txt_reason
    )
    Values 
    (
    @LeaveType,
    @IdEmployee,
    @DateFrom,
    @DateTo,
    @Reason
    )      
END
```

If anyone can give me better answer to make procedure correct.

I am very beginner of database.

thanks

Comment: parameters have to be enclosed with brackets. Also, what exactly do you want the procedure to return?

Comment: Your SELECT Query syntax is incorrect. SELECT is not written in this manner. Check out the SELECT syntax here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT @LeaveType=id_leave_type, @IdEmployee`=id_employee,@DateFrom=dt_from,@DateTo=dt_to,@Reason=txt_reason FROM cor_leave
```

Comment: Hi t-clausen, Could you please explain what mistake i have done?

Answer (score 2):

Your select statement is not valid SQL. It looks more like a modified INSERT statement.

It should be:

```
SELECT 
  id_leave_type,
  id_employee,
  dt_from,
  dt_to,
  txt_reason
FROM cor_leave
```

Comment: @AmmarAsjad - What you suggested (using `*` is not getting a _selection_ of columns, but all of them. It is also considered a bad practice for several reasons.